# UNITY3D - Orthographic Camera not render SHADER (2D GAME)

Tags: unity, shaders, rendering, camera

I have a problem with camera render, see the video please :) (note.: sorry for the music)

http://youtu.be/BB8rXIzIWVU

In Camera "Perspective", i can see the effect of shader:

[image]

In Camera "Orthographic", i not see the effect of shader: :(

[image]

I can do my shader is rendered from my perspective camera?

[EDITED]: The shader script:

```
Shader "Dvornik/Distort" {
Properties {
    _Refraction ("Refraction", Range (0.00, 100.0)) = 1.0
    _DistortTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "transparent" {}
}

SubShader 
{   
    Tags { "RenderType"="Transparent" "Queue"="Overlay" }
    LOD 100

    GrabPass 
    { 

    }

CGPROGRAM
#pragma exclude_renderers gles

#pragma surface surf NoLighting
#pragma vertex vert

fixed4 LightingNoLighting(SurfaceOutput s, fixed3 lightDir, fixed atten)
    {
        fixed4 c;
        c.rgb = s.Albedo; 
        c.a = s.Alpha;
        return c;
    }

sampler2D _GrabTexture : register(s0);
sampler2D _DistortTex : register(s2);
float _Refraction;

float4 _GrabTexture_TexelSize;

struct Input {
    float2 uv_DistortTex;
    float3 color;
    float3 worldRefl; 
    float4 screenPos;
    INTERNAL_DATA
};

void vert (inout appdata_full v, out Input o) {
  UNITY_INITIALIZE_OUTPUT(Input,o);
  o.color = v.color;
}

void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) 
{
    float3 distort = tex2D(_DistortTex, IN.uv_DistortTex) * IN.color.rgb;
    float2 offset = distort * _Refraction * _GrabTexture_TexelSize.xy;
    IN.screenPos.xy = offset * IN.screenPos.z + IN.screenPos.xy;    
    float4 refrColor = tex2Dproj(_GrabTexture, IN.screenPos);
    o.Alpha = refrColor.a;
    o.Emission = refrColor.rgb;
}
ENDCG
}
FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

This is a 2D game... How can I fix this?

Comment: Please stop rolling back changes to your post; this is a collaboratively-edited website and you don't hold exclusive rights over the content you post here. I have restored the original edits performed to the question as they are constructive and format the question in a more readable fashion.

Comment: The question no need revisions. Please stop locking threads without reasons. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to tweak the shader file.
Most probably there will be calculations based on the z axis.
You need to take out all the z axis consideration from the calculation.

For Example:-

```
o.pos.xy += offset * o.pos.z * _Outline;
```

Change to

```
o.pos.xy += offset * _Outline;
```

As every shader is different, I don't know if it will work for you, but it definitely fixed my problem :)

Edit :-
You need to edit the following line of your shader

```
 IN.screenPos.xy = offset * IN.screenPos.z + IN.screenPos.xy;
```

to

```
 IN.screenPos.xy = offset + IN.screenPos.xy;
```

Hope this works out :)

Comment: Hi @Hash Buoy, I did not find anything related to this in the shader, does even then the problem can be solved? See the question again please, I updated with the shader code. Thanks :)

Comment: edited the answer :)

Comment: Unfortunately is no change :( ! You can try to see the problem with this project:https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/106482752/Dvornik-Unity-Distortion.zip only (4MB). Thank you so much for this answer.

Comment: Hey can you share your email or skype as it will be faster to communicate.

Comment: The shader in the project you shared doesn't work, it shows square texture even for perspective camera . Can you share a working project where the shader is working fine for perspective cam.

Comment: Please one minute

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uelfl7rlthq1iee/Distortion-StackOverFlow.rar?dl=0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27572/discussion-between-igao-and-hash-buoy).